# Image Resizing Using Qt designer Layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have to design a GUI which has to display an image with it. And then generate a python file with it. Everything works fine until I add an image to the layout, after I add the image to the layout it resizes itself and I cannot reduce its size in the layout, I tried setting the size policy and all but nothing worked. Any idea of how to make the image size constant when put in a layout so that it does not expand.I even tried using spacers. I am using the PyQt4 module as it is one of the requirements.

Comment: First of all, *how* are you adding the image?

Comment: Using label and navigating through pixmap and selecting scaled contents @musicamante

Comment: QLabel doesn't support resizing to a size smaller than the source image. As an alternative, as long as you don't care about aspect ratio, you can use an empty QLabel or QFrame and set a proper stylesheet using `background-image`. Assuming that label or frame is named "myImage", the stylesheet would be: `QFrame#myImage { background-image: url(path/to/image); }`

Comment: Cant i do it in gui of qt designer itself ,is coding the only option?

Comment: What coding? You can set stylesheets on any widget in designer.

Comment: i couldn't figure it out, any video link or resource would help.

Comment: Click the label on designer, find "stylesheet" in the "property editor" and set it there. Then [study the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html).

Comment: Is there any way of changing the geometry of an image(label) in a layout?

Comment: If you want to specify a *fixed* size, just set both the maximum and the minimum. If you're asking about using a proportional size based on other widgets, read more about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and [stretch factors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#stretch-factors). If you want to allow resizing but while keeping a specific aspect ratio, as I already said in the first comment, you can't.